# Calculus: Work problem

Tags: definite-integrals

A cylindrical-shaped tank is filled with water at the level of 1 foot. Its height is 8 feet, diameter is 6 feet, and weight density of water is 62.4 lb-ft^3.

I've attempted to solve the work required to fill the tank to half, from the bottom.
From what I have gathered, `the volume would be pi 3^2, force = (62.4). (9). The distance would be 3 (4-1 as 4 is half of the tank's height, and 1 is the level that's already filled),` correct?

The integral is:
9pi . (62.4)h dh, from 1 to 4. Is this correct, am I missing the distance (3) or it's in the integration limits (1 foot level to half tank (4)?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @SakethMalyala just 9pi . (62.4)h dh then, right?